# Constructor Issues in Java

Tags: java, constructor, this

I'm very new to Java, and I can't seem to figure out why my code is not working. In theory, it should print out the distance between (0.0) and whatever I plug into the class. Can someone help me out please?

```
public class Homework61 {
    double x;
    double y;

    Homework61(double q, double r) {
        double x = q;
        double y = r;
    }

    Homework61() {
        x = 0.0;
        y = 0.0;
    }

    public String toString() {
        String a = "(" + x + "," + y + ")";
        return a;
    }

    public double distanceFromOrigin()

    {
        double z = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x, 2) + Math.pow(y, 2));
        return z;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Homework61 p = new Homework61();
        System.out.println(p.toString() + " Is this far from origin: "
                + p.distanceFromOrigin());
        p = new Homework61(3, 4);
        p.x = 3;
        p.y = 4;
        System.out.println(p.toString() + " Is this far from origin: "
                + p.distanceFromOrigin());
    }
}
```

Comment: Once you define a variable, you do not need to re-define its type (ex in `double x = q;`)

Answer (score 3):

```
Homework61(double q, double r) {
    double x = q;
    double y = r;
}
```

creates 2 local variable x and y then does nothing with them.
You probably mean

```
Homework61(double q, double r) {
    this.x = q;
    this.y = r;
}
```

Plus you only ever print the distance before you populate your objects (x and y are always 0).

Comment: I'd prefer `public` constructors unless the class is not meant to be instantiated.

Answer (score 1):

```
double x;
double y;

Homework61(double q, double r) {
        double x = q;
        double y = r;
    }
```

In the above case even through you have x and y class variable, Inside the constructor Homework61 again with the same name you are creating x and y local variables whose life will exits at the end of the constructor curly brackets.

if you want the receiving parameter values to be initialized in the declared x and y class variables use ***`this`*** pointer.

***`this`*** pointer is used to differentiate between local and class variables, i.e ***`it prevents the ambiguity between local variables and class variables`***

Therefore you have to initialize it like

```
Homework61(double q, double r) {
    this.x = q;
    this.y = r;
}
```